# Mixtures of log-convex functions are log-convex references

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, reference-request, convex-analysis

Here is a well-known, folklor-ish, and easily proved fact:

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. If the function $g\colon \mathbb R\times X\to\mathbb R$ is measurable and the function $t\mapsto g(t,x)$ is log-convex for each $x\in X$, then the "mixture" function $t\mapsto\int_X g(t,x)\mu(dx)$ is log-convex as well.

However, I cannot find a reference to it, even when $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. Can you help me with this?

I only need references, not proofs. I already have references to the fact that the sum of log-convex functions is log-convex, from which the highlighted result easily follows -- but I'd like to have a reference to the result just as stated, at least for the mentioned case when $X=\mathbb R$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.